# Got messy codes when crawling using urllib2 (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I used urllib2 but the response is like this:

```
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xed\x9d{s\xe2\xb8\x9a\x87\xff\xeeSu\xbe\x83\x0e\xc5\xce\xf4L\x11\xe2\x0b\xd7\x99\xee\xec*`\xc0\x1d_86\x84N\xb6\xb6\xa6\x1cp\x82\xa7\tfl\x93t\xce\xa7_\xc9@ \xc4\x18\xc5\t\xf1\xa8\xad\xae\x99t\xdb\xb1\xe5\xd7\x92~\xef\xa3W7\x7f\xfaWSo\xf4.\xba\x12\x18\x07\xb7\x13\xd0\xed\x9f*r\x03\xe4\x8e\x8e\x8f\x07b\xe3\xf8\xb8\xd9k\x82\xaf\x9d\x9e\xaa\x00\xbe\xc8\x81\x9egM}\'p\xdc\xa959>\x96\xb4\x1c\xc8\x8d\
```

and my code is:

```
url = "http://fsr.merckresponsibility.com/fsr/service.do?"
params = {"page": 2, "sort": "name", "descending": "asc", "letter": "all", "keytype": "", "keywords": "", "rows": 80}
params = urllib.urlencode(params)
header = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
          "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
          "Host": "fsr.merckresponsibility.com",
          "Cookie": "JSESSIONID=5D0AB9801BC9B522B043FC10C1705AF1.st3024;unique_visitor=60.254.142.39.1418022044678466; BIGipServerDMZ-04-Shared-HTTP=2926383",
          "Referer": "http://fsr.merckresponsibility.com/fsr/service.do",
          "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36"}

req = urllib2.Request(url + params, headers=header)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

Can anybody tell me where went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is passing `"Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch"` header which cause the server to encode the content using `gzip`.

Remove that header will solve your problem.

---

If you want to use `gzip` encoding, you need to decompress the response using [`gzip` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html):

```
...
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

import gzip
import StringIO
f = StringIO.StringIO(response)
zf = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
response = zf.read()
```